# Google cloud error assigning external ip to instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Assigning external IP to an existing instance from the external Ip list page (https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/list) gives the following error:

```
Google cloud instance External Ip Error: External IP address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx has a different network tier STANDARD from the network tier in instance access config PREMIUM.
```

Answer (score 5):

Can work around this by going via the instance details page

1. compute engine => vm instance => your instance
2. Scroll down to network interfaces and click the edit button
3. click the external ip dropdown and select your ip
4. Save your changes

More info on why this error occurs here: https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/using-network-service-tiers

To avoid issue in future make sure to select the correct network instance tier when creating the vm instance.

Comment: To extend on this - if you don't want to assign your own IP you can also just set the network tier to PREMIUM from STANDARD in the network interfaces and hit save. Now when going through the original question again of assigning the external IP, it should work w/o errors.